# How to validate selected item is null or not

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I wrote MVVM code in WPF. I want that if user selects nothing and click on edit button, it should display Message to user to select item first. With thing i am not getting clear is that how to put this validation before UpdateCommand. I need your suggestions. Thank You.
Here Code is:

```
 class UserViewModel
    {
    private IList<User> _UsersList;
    public User SelectedUser { get; set; }
    public UserViewModel()
        {
      _UsersList = new List<User>
        {
            new User{UserId = 1,FirstName="Raj",LastName="Beniwal",City="Delhi",State="DEL",Country="INDIA"},
            new User{UserId=2,FirstName="Mark",LastName="henry",City="New York", State="NY", Country="USA"},
            new User{UserId=3,FirstName="Mahesh",LastName="Chand",City="Philadelphia", State="PHL", Country="USA"},
            new User{UserId=4,FirstName="Vikash",LastName="Nanda",City="Noida", State="UP", Country="INDIA"},
            new User{UserId=5,FirstName="Harsh",LastName="Kumar",City="Ghaziabad", State="UP", Country="INDIA"},
            new User{UserId=6,FirstName="Reetesh",LastName="Tomar",City="Mumbai", State="MP", Country="INDIA"},
            new User{UserId=7,FirstName="Deven",LastName="Verma",City="Palwal", State="HP", Country="INDIA"},
            new User{UserId=8,FirstName="Ravi",LastName="Taneja",City="Delhi", State="DEL", Country="INDIA"}            
        };
 if(SelectedUser == null) { ShowNoUserSelectedWarning(); } // How to put this before UpdateCommand To Warn User

        }

    public IList<User> Users
        {
        get { return _UsersList; }
        set { _UsersList = value; }
        }
    public void ShowNoUserSelectedWarning()
        {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Warning");
        }


    private ICommand mUpdater;

    public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {

        get
            {
            if (mUpdater == null)
                mUpdater = new Updater();
            return mUpdater;
            }
        set
            {
            mUpdater = value;


            }
        }

    private class Updater : ICommand
        {
        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {


            return true;
            }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
            }
        #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml Code:

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Panel1" x:Name="Panel1">

                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ListView Name="UserGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,178,12,13"  ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView x:Name="grdTest">
                                <GridViewColumn Header="UserId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserId}"  Width="50"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"  Width="80" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Width="100" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="City" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City}" Width="80" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="State" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State}" Width="80" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Country" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Country}" Width="100" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>



                </Grid>


            </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
            <dxdo:LayoutPanel x:Name="Panel3">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Content="Edit"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
            <dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Panel2" x:Name="Panel2">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10">
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,7,0,0" Name="txtUserId" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserGrid,Path=SelectedItem.UserId}" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,35,0,0" Name="txtFirstName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserGrid,Path=SelectedItem.FirstName}" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,62,0,0" Name="txtLastName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserGrid,Path=SelectedItem.LastName}" />
                            <Label Content="UserId" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,274" Name="label1" />
                            <Label Content="Last Name" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,60,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <Label Content="First Name" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,35,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,143,0,0" x:Name="txtCity" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.City, ElementName=UserGrid}" />
                            <Label Content="Country" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,141,0,0" x:Name="label2_Copy" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,88,0,0" x:Name="txtCountry" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Country, ElementName=UserGrid}" />
                            <Label Content="City" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,86,0,0" x:Name="label2_Copy1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,115,0,0" x:Name="txtSTate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.State, ElementName=UserGrid}" />
                            <Label Content="State" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,113,0,0" x:Name="label2_Copy2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Button Content="Update" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,40,0,0" Name="btnUpdate" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"
            Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommad}"  />

                        <TextBox Width="166" Background="White" Height="33"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Text="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer.LastName,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```

**If my question is not clear to you Please ask .**

Comment: What people have been doing for this is that your 'edit' button does not become enabled until an item is selected.  Yours is always returning true, but should return false if something is not selected.

Comment: @GarryVass how to do this. Can you please briefly describe me as i am new to c#

Comment: I can fill out an answer that has some pseudo code that helps understand the command pattern for your particular case.  Is that likely to be acceptable or of any use to you?

Comment: Ok, when I get home, I'll add some code that explains how to wire up the command pattern and you'll be all set :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the WPF command pattern.  In your Xaml you have an items control like this...

```
 <ListView Name="UserGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,178,12,13"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}">
```

which is fine. and a button declared like this...

```
            <Button Content="Update" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,40,0,0" Name="btnUpdate" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"
                Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommad}"  />
```

which is also fine.  You do not want the button to fire unless the user has selected a User. To wire everything up, your View Model needs to look like this...

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // declare the command
    public ICommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {   // initialize the command
        UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteUpdateCommand, CanExecuteUpdateCommand);
    }
    #region UpdateCommand callbacks
    private bool CanExecuteUpdateCommand(object obj)
    {
        if (SelectedUser == null) return false;
        return true;
    }
    private void ExecuteUpdateCommand(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing the command");
    }
    #endregion // end of UpdateCommand callbacks

    private User _selectedUser;
    public User SelectedUser
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _selectedUser; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedUser)
            {
                _selectedUser = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This VM has a property called SelectedUser which is binded to your ListView and will track the whichever user has been selected.

The VM also has a property UpdateCommand as an instance of ICommand.  Now what's missing in your code is that UpdateCommand needs to be instantiated.  And this happens in the constructor...

```
UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteUpdateCommand, CanExecuteUpdateCommand);
```

It's instantiated as an instance of RelayCommand.  The two delegates are identified in the constructor, and of particular interest to you is the CanExecute delegate...

```
    private bool CanExecuteUpdateCommand(object obj)
    {
        if (SelectedUser == null) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

This tells the WPF binding engine that the button should not light up unless SelectedUser has a value in it.  And that's what you are trying to accomplish.  Easy peasy.  You were trying to roll your own version of ICommand, which is fine, but why bother, considering it's been written...

The last part is the RelayCommand.  Its role is discussed in Josh Smith's seminal article here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx  But for quick reference, here's the source...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace Commanding
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {   //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    }
}
```

Which you can paste in to your project.  Having said all of that, with this simple model you can use the command pattern on ANY button or menu item within WPF.  When the CanExecute method returns false, the UI element is disabled, when it returns true, the UI element is enabled.